# How to reduce the noise of a servo motor?

Tags: servo

I am new to motors.
Additional to put the servo in a box to reduce the noise physically,
Any good suggestions?
Or other motor option?
Thanks

Comment: How is this a electrical engineering question?

Comment: @OlinLathrop  This could be an electrical question, although it's missing a lot of details about the motor driver, control loop, nature of the noise, etc.  I had to change a driving waveform of an 60Hz AC motor once to reduce the noise.

Answer (score 2):

Use type [73 **ferrite** material](http://www.bourns.com/data/global/pdfs/fb_series.pdf) and create a common mode choke to absorb spikes 1~40MHz .

Wind the cable wires thru the core and choose a size that permits several turns.
They come in all sizes and are [**inexpensive**](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/FB73-287-RC/M8708-ND/775247) but need to be siliconed since they are brittle.

Comment: The OP is talking about audible noise-- which is why he talks about putting the servo in a box to "reduce the noise physically".  A common mode choke will not help that.